# How to approximate MySQL VARCHAR(n) into MAX_FILE_SIZE value in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do a front end control on the size of user inputs before they are loaded into a `VARCHAR(1000)` table. How should I do that given that I expect inputs in Latin and Asian character sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your varchar field size is 1000. First don't let user to type more than 1000 characters. You can control this from the front end.

If you have have a txtField you can use maxlenght

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" maxlength="1000" />
```

And if you use text area you can use following kind of code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function imposeMaxLength(Object, MaxLen)
{
  return (Object.value.length < MaxLen);
}

</script> 
<textarea name="txtxDesc" id="txtDesc" onkeypress="return imposeMaxLength(this, 1000);" ></textarea>
```

If you think advance user may cause problems by modifying DOM elements using tools. You have to validate this from server side as well using PHP.

```
if(strlen($_POST["txtxDesc"]) > 1000)
{
   echo "Text length is too much".
   exit;
}
```

Comment: The maxlength in characters isn't affected by whether the charset is latin or other?

Comment: I can't say exactly how it works with all the character sets. Basically I think it should be depend on how the computer identify a character. Hopefully I think it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do some checking with an if statement, and the strlen function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: Obvious ... once you know.  Thanks!